# Unclear about python async task cancel/shutdown at program exit

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I can't find docs that clearly describe the mechanism here so just want to try to understand and learn best practices. For tasks created by `asyncio.create_task`, they seem to be cleaned up at program end without generating any `CancelledError` or requiring a call to explicitly cancel the task. **Do we need to cancel to ensure orderly shutdown, or does the asyncio loop stuff just handle all this cleanly for us?**

Here's an example. The program seems to exit cleanly after 20s. So I'm assuming this idiom is fine. Just want to verify I'm not violating any best practices.

```py
import asyncio
import random
import time


async def forever_while_loop_task():
    while True:
        sleep_seconds = random.randint(5, 30)
        print(f'sleeping for {sleep_seconds} seconds')
        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_seconds)
        print('looping')


async def main():
    start = time.monotonic()
    the_looping_task = asyncio.create_task(forever_while_loop_task())
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    print(f'ok done with program, took {time.monotonic() - start:.2f}s')

    # Do I need to call the_looping_task.cancel() here 
    # or do anything to ensure orderly shutdown/cleanup?


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Sample output from a run:

```
sleeping for 12 seconds
looping
sleeping for 27 seconds
ok done with program, took 20.00s
```